# Algorithm for system of 2 linear equations with 2 variables

Tags: java, algorithm, equations

I've got a problem. I've come to the point where my app is able to solve simple system of 2 equations like this:

```
1x + 2y + 3 = 0, 2x + 3y + 4 = 0
```

I'm using elimination method. But what if one of the two numbers I want to multiply equation with equals 0? Then it would throw crap. Is there some algorithm to solve this without writing a couple of exceptions when a or b equals 0?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you know about Cramer algorithm for solving system of equations?

Comment: I've never heard of it. Can't find anything usable on Google, could you explain it?

Comment: It is the best way to solving such systems.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule

Comment: There exists a magic line to avoid exceptions:
if ( a == 0 )
Not sure what tag java has to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

[The pseudocode from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Pseudocode) includes a check to ensure that you don't divide by zero. For completeness, here is a copy:

```
for k = 1 ... m:
   Find pivot for column k:
   i_max  := argmax (i = k ... m, abs(A[i, k]))
   if A[i_max, k] = 0
     error "Matrix is singular!"
   swap rows(k, i_max)
   Do for all rows below pivot:
    for i = k + 1 ... m:
     Do for all remaining elements in current row:
      for j = k ... n:
       A[i, j]  := A[i, j] - A[k, j] * (A[i, k] / A[k, k])
     Fill lower triangular matrix with zeros:
     A[i, k]  := 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some algorithm to solve this without writing a couple of exceptions when a or b equals 0?

If the determinant is zero, there will be no solution. Unless you are okay throwing an `ArithmeticException` on division by zero, there will be no way to do this without using an extra if/else check, or a try/catch block.

Using Cramer's rule, which involves division by the determinant, in the 2x2 case is the most elegant way to program this I believe, as it does not specifically care which coefficients are zero; just that the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: It is not true, that there are no solutions if the determinant is zero. There may be no solution or infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a super simple solution using Python and sympy library to solve equations.

```
from sympy import solve, symbols
x,y = symbols('x,y')
sis = solve([x + 2 * y + 3, 2 * x + 3 * y + 4], [x,y])
print sis[x].evalf()
print sis[y].evalf()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended with a couple of (10) "if" statements. Those algorithms very pretty difficult (at least for me) to understand, as I'm only at high school. Anyway thank you very much for all responses :)